# Fetching data from Mysql DB to listView using JSON and PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to fetch data from mysql DB in android listview. But somehow I am not been able to display the data in the listView

I was trying this with the help of a tutorial,i.e., http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html

**Below is my MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private String jsonResult;
 private String url = "http://10.0.2.2/markit/login.php";
 private ListView listView;
 private TextView textv1;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  textv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  accessWebService();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee_name");
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee_no");
    String outPut = name + "-" + number;
    //textv1.setText(name);
    //textv1.setText(jsonResult);
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
  return employeeNameNo;
 }
}
```

**Below is mainactivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //replace with database hostname 
$username="root"; //replace with database username 
$password=""; //replace with database password 
$db_name="markit"; //replace with database name

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("markit")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from emp_info"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error or Exception?

Comment: no error but data is not visible in the list ...and it shows as many no of "-" as no of entry in the  database

Comment: I have tried to print the //textv1.setText(jsonResult);
Which results in total JSON result which we find after executing php in browser

Comment: try to Log your jsonResult and see what is coming form server. Is it valid json? and post that result here.

Comment: This is the result of printing jsonResult in a textView 


{"emp_info":[{"emp_no":"1","emp_name":"Ravi"},{"emp_no":"2","emp_name":"Div"},{"emp_no":"3","emp_name":"Harry"},{"emp_no":"4","emp_name":"Suresh"},{"emp_no":"5","emp_name":"Suu"}]}

Comment: see the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this

```
 String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee_name");
 String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee_no");
```

to

```
 String name = jsonChildNode.getString("emp_name");
 String number = jsonChildNode.getString("emp_no");
```