# Error on fetching data from Mysql DB with JSON and PHP

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I am learning to build android applications and I need some help whit getting data from MySQL. I followed [this tutorial](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html) to do it but I get this error:

> Error org.json.JSONEXception: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

On my MainActivity I have one button which when is clicked open second activity. The second activity must get and show data from DB. This is the code of second activity `Restaurant.java`

```
public class Restaurants extends Activity {
     private String jsonResult;
     private String url = "http://10.0.2.2/app1/GetRestaurants.php";
     private ListView listView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.restaurants);
         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         accessWebService();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
     }

    // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return null;
 }

 private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
     String rLine = "";
     StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

 try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    answer.append(rLine);
 }
}

 catch (IOException e) {
 // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
    return answer;
 }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     ListDrwaer();
   }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
     List<Map<String, String>> restaurantList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

 try {
     JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
     JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("restoranti");

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
     String menu = jsonChildNode.optString("menu");
     String outPut = name + "-" + menu;
     restaurantList.add(createRestaurants("restoranti", outPut));
   }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " + e.toString(),
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

 SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, restaurantList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "restoranti" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createRestaurants(String name, String menu) {
      HashMap<String, String> restaurantNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
      restaurantNameNo.put(name, menu);
      return restaurantNameNo;
 }
}
```

This is the restaurants.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
</ListView>
```

Please let me know if need to post some more code. Many thank's for help.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710281/1158599) to the post which is almost similar and tried to make the same but didn't work for me. Same error and blank page.

Comment: What's the content of response.getEntity().getContent(), where it seems that you are not getting a JSON object? PLUS you always return null (so no result in the same method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Maybe this will help ... 
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

// LETS RETURN SOMETING ... 
        return jsonResult;
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: This return `unfortunately app has stopped` and app crash. What you mean with `What's the content of response.getEntity().getContent()`?

Comment: Do you get a jsonResult ... what are you getting back from your call? Debug this part or log it ... to see what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded the file and DB on the remote host (internet) not on localhost and is working just fine. So the problem is in my localhost.